# Qt 5.1 Android - How to access NFC?

Tags: android, qt, nfc

I'm currently trying the bêta version of Qt 5.1 for Android. It seems it's working well, but  there is actually not any module or class that gives access to the NFC interface.

Is anybody knowing how to achieve that ?? Any examples or comments are welcome.

Maybe is there a possibility to call the Java Native Interface (JNI) to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NFC support in Qt exists only for Symbian^3 and Harmattan via old Qt Mobility module (which is split now into Qt Sensors and some other ones), so there is no such possibility to do it with Qt itself.

You can do it via JNI if you want, but of course it will not be portable anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I know I will lose portability, but it's better than doing nothing ;). Do you have some references or examples to know how to access JNI from Qt ?

Comment: Accessing Java through Qt is nothing different from accessing Java from non-Qt C++, so any JNI tutorials should be OK (i. e. http://code.google.com/p/awesomeguy/wiki/JNITutorial ).

Comment: @Gojir4: Did you manage to get this working? I need the exact same thing.

Comment: @Pat: Not yet. The solution was to call java with jni. But I didn't have time so I used Android sdk . but nfc support will be added to Qt 5.6 which will be released soon. But I think this only concerns Ndef protocol and not "low level" features of nfc (iso14443, iso15693, etc.). See here Qt 5.6 new features https://wiki.qt.io/New_Features_in_Qt_5.6

Comment: Yes, I have built Qt 5.6 from source but the API does not support low level access. How did you do it with the Android SDK?